# How do I do the equivalent of “git remote update” with jgit?

Tags: git, jgit

I'm managing git repos cloned with --mirror, and I need to do a `git remote update` using JGit.

Do I use a FetchCommand, or is there any other command?

What is the equivalent FetchCommand of a `git remote update`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `FetchCommand` and call `setRemote` to specify the name of the remote you want to fetch from.

If you have multiple remotes you want to fetch from, create a new `FetchCommand` instance for each remote you are fetching from.